# Heißt es jetzt eigentlich „Muslima“ oder „Muslimin“?

Tags: etymology, comparison

> Das Suffix *-in* ist in den hochdeutschen und oberdeutschen Dialekten
>   ein weibliches movierendes Suffix zur Bildung femininer Bezeichnungen
>   aus anderen Substantiven.
>
> Es findet sich besonders regelmäßig bei Ableitungen auf *-er*
>   (Lehrerin, Leiterin, Perückenmacherin, Schneiderin, Spielerin usw..)
>   sowie auch bei anderen Substantiven (Kandidatin, Köchin, Wirtin usw.).
>   Zurückzuführen ist das Suffix *-in* auf eine gemeingermanische
>   Suffixgruppe mit verschiedenen Ablautstufen; vom althochdeutschen
>   *-in*, *-inna*; vom mittelhochdeutsch *-īn*, *-inne*, im Alemannischen fällt das *-n* weg (Schnideri, Mülleri, Lehreri - die Lehrerin:
>   d’Lehreri). Niederdeutsch findet sich stattdessen ein weibliches
>   Suffix *-sche* und *-sch* (Kööksche, Börgermeestersch).[1]

[1] https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix

Sowohl *Muslima* als auch *Muslimin* stehen im Duden. Aber welche Form sollte man benutzen? Worin liegt der Unterschied? Und woher stammt das Wort *Muslima*, wo doch im Allgemeinen das weiblich movierende Suffix *-in* angewandt wird, um ein weibliches Nomen zu erstellen?

Comment: Du hättest auch direkt bei Wikipedia weiterlesen können: _Die weibliche Form im Deutschen ist Muslimin oder Moslemin. In jüngerer Zeit wird für die weibliche Form auch der arabische Begriff Muslima verwendet._ ([Muslim](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim))

Comment: https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Muslima

Comment: @chirlu: Und wieso ist das keine Antwort?

Comment: @chirlu genau das hätte ich auch ohne wikipedia gepostet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Endung -in ist die reguläre Endung, und die meisten Fremdwörter erhalten spätestens nach einiger Zeit die reguläre Grammatik. Die Anzahl der irregulären Wörter ist stark begrenzt, weil man sie ja auch alle einzeln lernen muss.

Answer (score 3):

Im Sinne guten, soliden Stils würde ich persönlich unbedingt

> die Muslimin

sagen. Dies ist die gute und dabei auch völlig neutrale Form, von einer Frau zu sprechen, die sich dem Islam zugehörig fühlt oder als solches zu erkennen gibt.

Die Form "die Muslima" dagegen, die in letzter Zeit immer häufiger zu hören ist, ist eine Form, die aus der unreflektierten Übernahme einer Wortform anderer Sprachen rührt (Arabisch مسلمة / muslima).

Nun ist es natürlich nichts Schlimmes, Ausdrücke aus anderen Sprachen zu übernehmen. Sprache entwickelt und ändert sich laufend und ist immer Einflüssen "von außen" ausgesetzt. Jedoch geschieht dies im Falle der *Muslima* in der Regel eben unreflektiert und in einem Akt vorauseilenden Gehorsams: "Oh, diese Leute nennen sich selbst so; dann darf ich nichts falsch machen und muss sie auch so nennen." (Kommentator LangLangC nennt das kurz "Hyperkorrektur".)

Dort wo dies die Motivation ist, vom etablierten Wort "Muslimin" abzuweichen und "Muslima" zu sagen, würde ich von *unreflektiert* sprechen. Denn dass sich bestimmte Leute selbst *Muslima* nennen, hat ja in der Regel einen von zwei Gründen: Entweder sie sind der deutschen Sprache nicht genügend mächtig und sind sich nicht bewusst, dass es mit "Muslimin" ein etabliertes (und keineswegs pejoratives) Wort gibt.

Dies mag noch der bessere Fall sein. Im schlechteren steckt hinter der Verwendung des Wortes *Muslima* gar eine verdeckt-aggressive Forderung nach einer Sonderbehandlung der eigenen sozialen Gruppe, also eine politische Programmatik, hinter der man auch eine Geringschätzung der deutschen Umgebungskultur nicht immer ausschließen kann ("Ungläubige").

Doch warum sollten wir in der deutschen Sprache eine bestimmte Bevölkerungsgruppe mit sprachlichen Sonderregeln bedenken, in deren Genuß andere Bevölkerungsgruppen nicht kommen? Wenn wir *Muslima* sagen, müssten wir gerechterweise auch *Christa* und *Juda* sagen. Was wir aber nicht tun. Wie wir überhaupt Abstand genommen haben davon, der Privatsache Religion im öffentlichen Leben zu große Bedeutung beizumessen. Jemand kann sich gut und gerne als Jude, Christ, Buddhist oder was auch immer fühlen, wird damit aber nicht unbedingt hausieren gehen.

Ich sehe auch keine besonderen alltagspraktischen Vorteile, *Muslima* zu sagen, denn das Wort ist nicht kürzer oder leichter auszusprechen als *Muslimin*. Noch dazu sagen wir auch nicht Arabera oder Türka sondern bleiben hier schön bei Araberin und Türkin. (Na gut, das letzte war polemisch, denn *Arabera* und *Türka* würden nicht auf auf ähnlich klingenden Wortformen bzw. Selbstbezeichnungen in den Herkunftssprachen beruhen sondern wären eher eine übergriffige Suffixverwendung.)

Anmerkung noch: Natürlich kann sich jede/r nennen, wir si/e/r will, auch Christa. Meine Kritik richtet sich mehr gegen die unbedachte Übernahme solcher Wörter in Bereiche der Gesellschaft, wo  bewusster Umgang mit Sprache wichtig wäre wie z.B. in den Medien.

Comment: Sagst Du auch "der Muslim" oder "der Moslem"?

Comment: Hm. "Von außen" Ich seh da die Fälle von Migranten, Konvertiten und vermeintlich auch sonst hyperkorreigierenden Sprechern (dein nix falsch machen). Solange sich keine allgemein anerkannte Negativbedeutung für -in Variante durchsetzt sehe ich -a vor allem als modisch (WP: "zunehmend"), dämlich korrekt und ein relativ häufiges Anzeichen für -isten in der Selbstbezeichnung. Letzteres beschwingt doch eher eine negative Konnotation für -a.

Comment: Ich denke, diese Antwort stellt stilistische Regeln auf, die schwer haltbar sind - Sagt man zu einer französischen Frau jetzt "Madame" oder "Madamin"?

Comment: @userunknown. Im Deutschen sage ich brav und altmodisch "der Muslim". Das aus dem englischen Kommende "der Moslem" vermeide ich. Beide gehen natürlich auf exakt das gleiche arabische Wort zurück, aber die Traditionen der Transkription arabischer Wörter in der angelsächsischen und deutschen Orientalistik waren von jeher anders. Es gibt keinen guten Grund, sie heute zu vermischen.

Comment: @tofro   Lustig, aber auf wackligen Füssen. "Madame" ist immerhin eine Anredeform, die über Jahrhunderte etabliert war. "Muslimin" ist überhaupt keine Anrede sondern eine Gruppenbezeichung. Oder sagst du zu deiner Nachbarin: "Hallo Muslima Öztürk?"

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Moslem kommt aus dem Arabischen über das  Persische (Aussprache). Vor wenigen Jahrzehnten noch war es entweder Muselman oder Moslem. Beides die weniger wahhabitischen türkischen Wurzeln freilegend. Schau mal die jetzige türkische Eigenbezeichnung auf türkisch an.

Comment: Meine iranischen Freundinnen empfinden die -u- Aussprache übrigens als unangenehm (bis…, den Rest zensier ich mal selbst) und sagen "Ich bin Moslemin"

Comment: @LangLangC Türk sözü müsliman dir, biliyorum. - Das mit der persischen Empfindlichkeit ist allerdings ein interessanter ergänzender Aspekt.

Comment: Interessant übrigens, wo wir über die verschiedenen möglichen Schreibungen von Muslim/Moslem/Muselman sprechen: Seven Pillars of Wisdom (Lawrence of Arabia), Vorwort, wo er die Entstehungsgeschichte des Buchs erzählt: Dort distanziert er sich explizit von jeglichem Anspruch, arabische Namen immer gleich zu schreiben. Begründung: "Die Araber schreiben sie ja auch bei jedem Vorkommen anders."

Comment: @tofro   Man sagt *Madame*, weil es sich als Anrede etabliert hat, nachdem Franzöisch halt lange Zeit lingua franca bestimmter Kreise war. Man sagt aber - hoppala - *Prinzessin*. Also kein Punkt, der gegen *Muslimin* spräche.

Comment: @userunknown   Ich sage in der Praxis auf Deusch stets *Muslim* (weil es die herkömmliche Wortform im Deutschen ist. Aber jetzt, da du das hier zum Thema machst, überlege ich, ob ich in Zukunft nicht lieber *Müslim* sage; damit die türkische Form des Wortes auch  mal zu ihrem Recht kommt. Und noch dazu ist man dann frei von allen Tücken der Transliteration, da das Türkeitürkische ja dankenswerterweise heute das lateinische Alphabet verwendet (mit ein paar Diakritika, die wie bei ö und ü dem Deutschen aber sehr gelegen sind).